# angular/material2 mat-spinner resize

Tags: html, css, angular-material2

Is there any possible way to change size of `mat-spinner` or `mat-progress-circle`?

I read the documentation of `mat-spinner` and `mat-progress-circle` but they said that `mat-diameter` is discontinued and the spinner will take the parent element's size.

How can I put `mat-spinner` in a `mat-button` to the left corner without changing the height of the button?

```
<button mat-button>
   <mat-spinner style="float:left;"></mat-spinner> 
   processing....
</button>
```

I also tried to change the height using in-line css like

```
style="float:left;height:10px;width:10px;
```

but is not pretty to see.

Comment: Have you tried with transform: scale(num) ?

Comment: transform: scale(num) is working for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure why your styling did not bring the desired results. As you mentioned,  the `svg` content inside `md-spinner` will scale to the container's size, so applying `width` and `height` to the `md-spinner` should work.

**CSS**

```
md-spinner {
  float:left; 
  width: 24px; 
  height: 24px; 
  margin: 5px 10px 0px 0px;
}
```

**Template**

```
<button md-raised-button>
  <md-spinner></md-spinner>Raised Button with spinner
</button>
```

**Plunk**

http://plnkr.co/edit/RMvCtOCV9f4TxgB4G0Yz?p=preview

Is this what you'd like to achieve?

Comment: It didn't work for me either until I added `!important` to all of the styles.

Answer (score 298):

With the latest update you should use the `diameter` property:

```
<mat-spinner [diameter]="70"></mat-spinner>
```

The diameter represents the amount of pixels for both the width and the height of the spinner. In this case it has a size of 70x70 pixels.

See the following stackblitz example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-progress-spinner

Comment: Nice examples in your link.

Comment: Perfect, so I had nice loaders that adjusts for mobile, now this. Hehe Web Dev though.

Comment: Are there any official guidelines about a good size for mobile? The default size which is 100 is MASSIVE on mobile. 70 does seem perfect though :-)

Comment: Setting it a static size is good. But what if I need to make it responsive?

Comment: If you get spinner shaking, see https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11756

Answer (score 16):

here is the answer :

```
<mat-spinner mode="indeterminate" style="margin:0 auto;" [diameter]="30"></mat-spinner>
```

Answer (score 9):

you can add this to your css file:

```
mat-spinner {
  zoom: 0.2
}
```

Comment: [zoom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom#Specifications) is nonstandard and firefox doesn't support it